# How to solve the fopen error?

Tags: debug, internal-server-error

I recently updated xampp to 1.8 and enabled xdebug. I'm not sure if this is the reason for this error message which I didn't see before:

```
Warning: fopen(http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/): in C:\xampp\htdocs\wodpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 923
```

Maybe I did something wrong at server configure. but there isn't really anything more than enable xdebug. Need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a warning, not an error. Turn off the PHP display_errors configuration directive.